# Error on PUT/DELETE operation in AWS OpenSearch "Authorization failure for the following indices: [trip-list]"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-opensearch

I am running my code in AWS Lambda to push data into AWS OpenSearch. I have provided full permissions (es:* and aoss:*) for the user whose credentials I am using to PUT/DELETE data into OpenSearch. But, I am getting the following error...

```
    {
    "name": "ResponseError",
    "meta": {
        "body": {
            "error": {
                "root_cause": [
                    {
                        "type": "security_exception",
                        "reason": "Authorization failure for the following indices: [trip-list]"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "Authorization failure for the following indices: [trip-list]"
            },
            "status": 403
        },
        "statusCode": 403,
        "headers": {
            "date": "Sun, 09 Jul 2023 16:13:35 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "241",
            "x-envoy-upstream-service-time": "75",
            "server": "aoss-amazon-i",
            "x-request-id": "143de425-85d0-9851-9d8f-406091505e0d"
        },
        "meta": {
            "context": null,
            "request": {
                "params": {
                    "method": "PUT",
                    "path": "/trip-list/_doc/34c41782-21ed-4bdf-8900-2e1847d63080",
                    "body": "{\"id\":\"34c41782-21ed-4bdf-8900-2e1847d63080\",\"a\":\"US_Mexico_Trip\",\"b\":2000,\"c\":20230706113628772}",
                    "querystring": "",
                    "headers": {
                        "user-agent": "opensearch-js/1.2.0 (linux 4.14.255-311-248.529.amzn2.x86_64-x64; Node.js v18.16.0)"
                    },
                    "timeout": 30000
                },
                "options": {},
                "id": 1
            },
            "name": "opensearch-js",
            "connection": {
                "url": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/",
                "id": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com/",
                "headers": {},
                "deadCount": 0,
                "resurrectTimeout": 0,
                "_openRequests": 0,
                "status": "alive",
                "roles": {
                    "master": true,
                    "data": true,
                    "ingest": true
                }
            },
            "attempts": 0,
            "aborted": false
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code I have written in Lambda

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

import { Client } from "@opensearch-project/opensearch";
import { AwsSigv4Signer } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch/aws';
export const handler = async (event) => {

    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });

    const client = new Client({
        ...AwsSigv4Signer({
            region: 'eu-west-1',
            service: 'aoss',
            getCredentials: () =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    AWS.config.getCredentials((err, credentials) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(credentials);
                        }
                    });
                }),
        }),
        node: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.aoss.amazonaws.com', // OpenSearch domain URL
    });


    var index_name = "trip-list";

    for (const record of event.Records) {
        const eventName = record.eventName;
        const dynamodbItem = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(record.dynamodb.NewImage);

        if (eventName === 'INSERT' || eventName === 'MODIFY') {
            const PK = dynamodbItem.PK;
            const SK = dynamodbItem.SK;
            const a = dynamodbItem.a
            const b = dynamodbItem.b
            const c = dynamodbItem.c;

            // Create an Elasticsearch document from the extracted data
            const document = {
                id: SK,
                a,
                b,
                c
            };

            try {
                var response = await client.index({
                    id: SK,
                    index: index_name,
                    body: document
                });
                console.log("UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY -> ")
                console.log(response)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error indexing document:');
                console.error(JSON.stringify(error))
            }

        } else if (eventName === 'REMOVE') {
            const SK = dynamodbItem.SK;

            // Delete the corresponding document from Elasticsearch
            try {
                var response = await client.delete({
                    index: index_name,
                    id: SK
                });
                console.log('Document deleted successfully:', JSON.stringify(response));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error deleting document:');
                console.error(JSON.stringify(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The role which is assigned to Lambda has also been given full permission (es.* and aoss.*). Then, why am I still getting **Authorization failure for the following indices: [trip-list]**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide full access to opensearch for the specific IAM user on AWS, and you need to add the user to the security configuration by mapping and adding roles in opensearch dashboard.

Once this is done, you can access the indices from Node.js.